# Prove that if $f: A\to B$ and $B \to C$, then $gf: A \to C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $a \in A$. Since $f$ is a function, there's unique $b \in B$ such that $f(a) = b$. Let $b \in B$. Since $g$ is a function, there's unique $c \in C$ such that $g(b) = c$.

Thus $gf(a) = g(f(a)) = g(b) = c$. So, $(a, c) \in gf$ implying $a$ in the domain of $gf$. Then $A$ is a subset of the domain of $gf$. We'll have the the domain of $gf$ equal $A$ if the domain of $gf$ is a subset of $A$. How do we show the domain of $gf$ is the subset of $A$? That would probably prove that the domain of $gf$ is $A$. Then how do we show the codomain of $gf$ is $C$ and that $gf$ is well-defined?

Answer (score 0):

If x is not in A then f(x) is not defined. so g(f(x)) is not defined so x is not in the domain of gf.  If a is in A then g(f(a)) exists.  So x is in the domain of  A.  So domain of gf is A.

You haven't actually claimed that B is the codomain of f.  (The codomain could just be a proper subset of B).  Nor that the codomain of g is all of C.

In general, f maps points of A into points of B so the codomain of f is a subset of B.  g maps points of B to points of C so it maps points of the subset of B to points of C.  So the codomain of gf is a subset of C.

*If* you claim B and C are codomains then for every point of c in C there is a b in B s.t. g(b) = c. (This *ISN"T* true in general!). For every point b' of B you assumed there is a point a' in A s.t. f(a') = b' (Again, not always true).  So there exists a point a in A s.t. f(a) = b. (This is the b s.t. g(b) = c).  so g(f(a)) = c.  So C is the codomain of gf.  BUT this isn't always true.  But the codomain of gf is always a subset of C.

well defined means every point of A maps to exactly one point of C.  You've shown that.